# ASP.NET WebAPI - How do I receive Base64 encoded binary from JSON post?

Tags: c#, json, binary, base64, blob

I want to send a BLOB to my API. I've got a model with two properties: `Id (int)`, `Blob (byte[])`... How is this received by the WebAPI controller? Will it recognize the model and convert the Base64 encoded BLOB from the JSON into a `byte[]`? Currently I'm able to receive the Id, but not the Blob (it was sent through XHR without any problems)